# help with a sql query - joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this

Table1 --> route_table

```
route_id | BusNumber | StartStationID | DestStationID  
1        |   90D     |    1           |       2  
2        |   100A    |    1           |       1
```

Table2 --> station_table

```
stationId  |  stationname  
1          |   Jadcherla  
2          |   Hyderabad
```

I want to write a sql query to join the above two tables and generate this table

```
BusNumber |  StartStation  |  DestStation  
  90D     |    Jadcherla   |   Hyderabad  
  100A    |    Jadcherla   |   Jadcherla
```

I tried using inner joins but unable to report three columns. I couldn't figure out any keyword to google for this. New to sql, sorry if this is a basic question

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT BusNumber, 
       Start.stationname AS StartStation, 
       Dest.stationname  AS DestStation
FROM route_table
INNER JOIN station_table Start ON Start.stationId = StartStationID
INNER JOIN station_table Dest  ON End.stationId   = EndStationID
```

Answer (score 1):

A left join will do it:

```
SELECT busnumber, d1.stationname, d2.stationname FROM route_table
LEFT JOIN dest d1 ON StartStationID = d1.stationId
LEFT JOIN dest d2 ON StartStationID = d2.stationId
```

Proved working

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
rt.BusNumber, startStation.stationname, destStation.stationname
FROM rout_table rt
LEFT JOIN station_table startStation ON rt.StartStationID = startStation.stationId
LEFT JOIN station_table destStation ON rt.DestStationID = destStation.stationId
```